# How to plot a bloxplot in R with subsets

Tags: r, subset, boxplot

My data set "olympics" has 4 columns: case number, height, sport, and sex (female=F, male=M), and each row corresponds to an athlete.

I need to produce a box plot comparing the height distributions among the male basketball players and male football players. (Both sports on a single plot, but with no others.)

I have tried

```
boxplot(olympics$height[olympics$sex == "M" & olympics$sport %in% c("basketball", "football")])
```

but I keep getting errors saying that finite `ylim` values are needed. How would you get the correct boxplot?

Comment: Wouldn't the examples in the `?boxplot` help page be exactly analogous to this question? Hard to say what is your problem since there no data or even `str` results from `olympics`. Infinite values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to rewrite this since I found your data set and figured out what your issue was. You have a ton of typos. R is case sensitive. Run this code and it will produce the boxplots that you want.

```
library(VGAMdata)
data(oly12)

dat = oly12

dat = dat[dat$Sport %in% c("Basketball","Football"),]
dat$Sport = droplevels(dat$Sport)
dat = dat[dat$Sex == "M",]
boxplot(dat$Height ~ dat$Sport)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, my only problem now is that when I put dat$Sport = droplevels(dat$Sport) I get an error saying "no applicable method for 'droplevels' applied to an object of class "NULL"". Do you have any idea why this may be?

Comment: @Lucinda it sounds like nothing is saved under Dat. Try to print out Dat and see if anything is there.

Comment: @Lucinda if you want to paste your code I can tell you what's going on.