# errors occurred when box plotting using subset command by using R language

Tags: r, plot, subset, boxplot

I want to compare between male basketball player's height and male football players's height by doing box plot. but there's some error occurred when plotting it.I read the data first

**> olympic<-read.table(file="olympic_height.txt", header=T)

> names(olympic)
>   [1] "height" "sport"  "sex"
>   olympic
>         height                                                    sport sex
>   1        170                                                     Judo   M
>   2        193                                                Athletics   M
>   3        187                                                Athletics   M
>   4         NA                                                   Boxing   M
>   5        178                                                Athletics   F
>   6        182                                                 Handball   M
>   7        182                                                   Rowing   F
>   8        187                                                 Football   M**

then I type these commands but there's mistake

```
                                                                         **> B<- subset(olympic,sport=="basketball")
```

> BM<- subset(B,sex=="M")
>   boxplot(BM$height)
>   Error in plot.window(xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, log = log, yaxs = pars$yaxs) : 
>     need finite 'ylim' values
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
>   2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
>   **

I tried another way but still doesn't work

**> BM <- subset(olympic,sport=="basketball" & sex == 'M')

> boxplot(BM$height)
>   Error in plot.window(xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, log = log, yaxs = pars$yaxs) : 
>     need finite 'ylim' values
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
>   2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf**

the same problem.I really don't know what is wrong? there's thousands of data set by the way not just those up.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2747709 - please ask a reproducible R question!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to plot a bloxplot in R with subsets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36409627/how-to-plot-a-bloxplot-in-r-with-subsets)
R is case-sensitive. So type the variable names and values exactly as displayed.

Comment: I've tried the method in my computer but still doesn't work

Comment: Edit your post and add the result of `dput(BM)` or the smaller `dput(head(BM))`, if `boxplot(head(BM$height))` reproduces the error, too. In addition, it would be nice to reference your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36528416/r-software-making-boxplot-need-finite-ylim-value so that people can see what did not work.

Comment: thank you for mentioning my previous question.                                            > BM<- subset(B,sex=="M")
> boxplot(head(BM$height))
Error in plot.window(xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, log = log, yaxs = pars$yaxs) : 
  need finite 'ylim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
> dput(BM)<- subset(B,sex=="M")
Error in dput(BM) <- subset(B, sex == "M") : 
  could not find function "dput<-"
>            but I tried, still same problem

Comment: @XiaohuiZhu type this and check again `BM <- subset(olympic, Sport == "Basketball" & Sex == "M")` and then `boxplot(BM$Height)`. Note the capitalization, as R is case-sensitive.